# switching view controllers using swipe gestures

Tags: ios, objective-c, viewcontroller, uiswipegesturerecognizer

Okay so here is the problem I'm running into:

I am attempting to switch from one `viewController` that I named `MenuViewController` which contains my menu (obviously). I have a separate `viewController` named `ViewController` that contains my `mapView`. I would like to be able to double finger `swipe left` from my `MenuViewController` over to my `mapView`.

I'm not exactly sure where to start.

Also, I am using xib files, and not the storyboard. Running iOS 6.

Answer (score 12):

```
UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeLeftGesture=[[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSwipeGesture:)];
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:swipeLeftGesture];
swipeLeftGesture.direction=UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft;

-(void)handleSwipeGesture:(UIGestureRecognizer *) sender
{
    NSUInteger touches = sender.numberOfTouches;
    if (touches == 2)
    {
        if (sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded)
        { 
            //Add view controller here    
        }
    }  
}
```

Comment: And this would go into my viewDidLoad correct? What goes into my header file? Also, how exactly would I "add view controller here"?

Comment: put the swipe gesture code(first 3 lines in my ans) in viewDidLoad. Nothing in .h file. Allocate your view controller & just push, add or present it in handleSwipeGesture method.

Comment: This is how I added my viewController to that line and it's not working:                                                          ViewController *mapView = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:mapView animated:YES];

Comment: Where you are allocating navigation controller? Just explain how you are adding the view controllers on it.

Answer (score 4):

once go through this,

```
UISwipeGestureRecognizer  *swipeLeft = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleleftSwipe:)];
swipeLeft.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1;//give required num of touches here ..
swipeLeft.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft;
swipeLeft.delegate = (id)self;
[self. view addGestureRecognizer:swipeLeft];

UISwipeGestureRecognizer  *swipeRight = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handlerightSwipe:)];
swipeRight.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1;//give required num of touches here ..
swipeRight.delegate = (id)self;
swipeRight.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight;
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:swipeRight];
```

now define swipe methods like below:

```
 -(void)handleleftSwipe:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)recognizer{
//Do ur code for Push/pop..
  }
-(void)handlerightSwipe:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)recognizer{
 //Do ur code for Push/pop..
  }
```

Hope it helps you...

Answer (score 1):

Try this...

**in .h file**

```
@interface MenuViewController : UIViewController {
    ViewController *mapViewObj;
}
```

**in .m file**

```
-(void) viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    mapViewObj = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil];

    UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeLeftGesture=[[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSwipeGesture:)];
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:swipeLeftGesture];
    swipeLeftGesture.direction=UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft;
}

-(void)handleSwipeGesture:(UIGestureRecognizer *) sender {
    NSUInteger touches = sender.numberOfTouches;
    if (touches == 2)     {
        if (sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded)    {
            //push mapViewObj over here..
            [self.navigationController pushViewController:mapViewObj animated:YES];
        }
    }  
}
```

Comment: Ah, to no avail good sir. I loaded it up into my header and implementation file. I'm not sure if I'm doing this correctly either, but I'm actually using the Google maps API. Does the mapView not go directly into the default ViewController? I appreciate your efforts, though.

Comment: replace your code at line **[self.navigationController pushViewController:mapViewObj animated:YES];**

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm not following. What should I replace that section of code with?

Answer (score 1):

This is what I coded for you.

```
//add gesture recogniser to your view
[self addSwipegestureToView:self.view];


- (void) addSwipegestureToView : (UIView *) view{
    UISwipeGestureRecognizer *_swipegestureRecogniser = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(swipeGesturePerformed)];
    _swipegestureRecogniser.numberOfTouchesRequired = 2;
    [_swipegestureRecogniser setDirection:UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft];
    [view addGestureRecognizer:_swipegestureRecogniser];
}

- (void) swipeGesturePerformed{
    SecondViewController *object = [[SecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecondViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:object animated:YES];
}
```

What you only need to have is,  `currentViewController` must have `navigationController` for appropriate push (slide in) navigation.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you cannot use the built in navigation mechanism.

You will need to add the view of the 'ViewController' to the view of 'MenuViewController' and I recommend you add 'ViewController' as a child view controller to the 'MenuViewController'.

After that, set the frame of 'ViewController' out side of the screen, and when you swipe or do your gesture, just animate it back to the screen.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a perfect time to use [UIGestureRecognizer](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html) or, more specifically, [UISwipeGestureRecognizer](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UISwipeGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UISwipeGestureRecognizer)